# Angular8 service unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular8

In my project there is a sharedService in the share folder that is called into all the services.
In fact, my services send their request to this sharedService and the sharedService send a http request according to the url that it received.
How do I write a unitTest for my services?

> sharedService has Api method:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

export class SharedService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }


  Api(method, url): Observable<any> {
    this.httpClient.request(method, url).subscribe( );
  }

}
```

> The usersService in the users module send its request to the Api
>   method in sharedService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'app/shared/services/shared.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class usersService {

  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) { }

  GetUsers() {
    return this.sharedService.Api('get' , 'url');
  }
}
```

> How do I write for usersService unitTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this. SharedService returns an array of username for this example.

```
describe('usersService ', () => {
  let userService;
  let sharedService;
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        SharedService,
        UsersService
      ]
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    userService = TestBed.get(UsersService);
    sharedService = TestBed.get(SharedService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(userService).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should test GetUsers()', () => {
    spyOn(sharedService, 'Api').and.returnValue(of(['user 1', 'user2']));
    userService.GetUsers().subscrbe(data => {
      expect(sharedService.Api).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(data).toEqual(['user 1', 'user2'])
    })
  })

})
```